# Applying 2d gaussian filter in a circular image area - Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering

Is there an easy way to apply a 2d gaussian filter in a circular image area (by easy i mean a ready matlab function) or does one have to implement this on his own ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to apply any filter to a selected portion of the image, one option is to use a binary mask.

Let `img` be your image, set the position and the radius of the circular mask as well as the dimension of the filter:

```
centre=[50 50];
radius=20;
n=5;
```

Then create the mask:

```
Mask=zeros(size(img));
Disk = fspecial('disk',radius)==0;
Mask(centre(1)-radius:centre(1)-radius+size(Disk,1)-1, centre(2)-radius:centre(2)-radius+size(Disk,2)-1)=double(~Disk);
```

Apply filtering as suggested by @Gacek:

```
h = fspecial('gaussian', n);
Filtered=filter2(h, img);
```

Combine the filtered area with the original image and show the result:

```
Result=img.*uint8(~Mask)+uint8(Filtered.*Mask);
imshow(Result)
```

Example result:

[image: filtered lion]

Notes: 1. change the class `uint8` to the appropriate class of your original image. 2. The example image is in the public domain, source: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Phase_correlation.png.

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer.  The other answers apply the filter **on the entire image**, which isn't what the OP is asking for.  BTW +1 from me!

Comment: @rayryeng merely a matter of interpreting the question.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `fspecial`. Given `img` is your image, then:

```
h = fspecial('gaussian', n);
filter2(h, img);
```

where `n` is the size of your filter mask. So it will create `n`x`n` Gaussian filter mask.

[The documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html) also says you can set the standard deviation for your Gaussian mask with another parameter:

```
h = fspecial('gaussian', n, std_sigma);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`fspecial`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/fspecial.html) with [`imfilter`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/imfilter.html) -

```
h = fspecial('gaussian', hsize, sigma);
filteredIMG = imfilter(originalIMG, h);
```

**Example**

```
originalIMG = imread('cameraman.tif');
h = fspecial('gaussian', 21, 0.9);
filteredIMG = imfilter(originalIMG, h);

figure,
subplot(211),imshow(originalIMG)
subplot(212),imshow(filteredIMG)
```

[image]

Comment: is fspecial supposed to create a filter that can be applied in a circular image area??

Comment: Exactly! `fspecial` has some commonly used kernels. Of course you can use your own custom made `hsize`x `hsize` sized kernels and replace with `h` for use in `imfilter` as the second parameter in the example.

Comment: @obelix On second thought, `fspecial` is for various commonly used kernels, not necessarily circular kernels like `gaussian`.