# Apply a gaussian distribution in a specific part of an image

Tags: matlab

I have for example the following image and a corresponding mask.

[image]     [image]

I would like to weight the pixels inside the white circle with a Gaussian, `g = @(x,y,xc,yc) exp(-( ((x-xc)^2)/0.5 + ((y-yc)^2)/0.5 ));`, placed in the [centroid](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) `(xc,yc)` of the mask. `x`, `y` are the coordinates of the corresponding pixels. Could you please someone suggest a way to do that **without** using for loops?

Thanks.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22914519/2777181

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applying 2d gaussian filter in a circular image area - Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910326/applying-2d-gaussian-filter-in-a-circular-image-area-matlab)

Comment: I'm not so sure it's a duplicate. It is a bit unclear but the question never asks for a gaussian filter to be applied, just to weight the pixels within the circular mask. If this is truly the case it is a different problem however that does not seem exceptionally useful.

Comment: I think that I am asking is different from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910326/applying-2d-gaussian-filter-in-a-circular-image-area-matlab). Look @jucestain first snippet .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "weighting" pixels inside the ellipse, I assume you mean multiply elementwise by a 2D gaussian. If so, here's the code:

```
% Read images
img = imread('img.jpg');
img = im2double(rgb2gray(img));
mask = imread('mask.jpg');
mask = im2double(rgb2gray(mask)) > 0.9; % JPG Compression resulted in some noise

% Gaussian function
g = @(x,y,xc,yc) exp(-(((x-xc).^2)/500+((y-yc).^2)./200)); % Should be modified to allow variances as parameters

% Use rp to get centroid and mask
rp_mask = regionprops(mask,'Centroid','BoundingBox','Image');

% Form coordinates
centroid = round(rp_mask.Centroid);
[coord_x coord_y] = meshgrid(ceil(rp_mask.BoundingBox(1)):ceil(rp_mask.BoundingBox(1))+rp_mask.BoundingBox(3)-1, ...
                             ceil(rp_mask.BoundingBox(2)):ceil(rp_mask.BoundingBox(2))+rp_mask.BoundingBox(4)-1);

% Get Gaussian Mask
gaussian_mask = g(coord_x,coord_y,centroid(1),centroid(2));
gaussian_mask(~rp_mask.Image) = 1; % Set values outside ROI to 1, this negates weighting outside ROI

% Apply Gaussian - Can use temp variables to make this shorter
img_g = img;
img_g(ceil(rp_mask.BoundingBox(2)):ceil(rp_mask.BoundingBox(2))+rp_mask.BoundingBox(4)-1, ...
     ceil(rp_mask.BoundingBox(1)):ceil(rp_mask.BoundingBox(1))+rp_mask.BoundingBox(3)-1) =  ...
     img(ceil(rp_mask.BoundingBox(2)):ceil(rp_mask.BoundingBox(2))+rp_mask.BoundingBox(4)-1, ...
     ceil(rp_mask.BoundingBox(1)):ceil(rp_mask.BoundingBox(1))+rp_mask.BoundingBox(3)-1) .* gaussian;

% Show
figure, imshow(img_g,[]);
```

The result:

[image]

If you instead want to perform some filtering within that roi, there's a function called `roifilt2` which will allow you to filter the image within that region as well:

```
img_filt = roifilt2(fspecial('gaussian',[21 21],10),img,mask);
figure, imshow(img_filt,[]);
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I think the first snippet is what I am asking.

Comment: @Thoth If it's what you were looking for can you accept the answer?

Comment: I would like to play with the code before accept the post in case I have any question :)